# Small image of iPad circled on iPad: meaning?

Tags: ipad

First time I’ve ever seen this.  A little box appeared on the iPad Home Screen, containing a green circle around a picture of an iPad.

Tapping it has no effect.  It’s on the right, beneath the app suggestions.

**What is it for?**

[image]

Comment: Hi @WGroleau - is your battery fully charged ?  If you had airpods they'd show there tooo..

Comment: Well, now that I know what it is and how to read it, it does show fully charged, which is probably at that time.  But how it got added is puzzling.  It wasn't there when I plugged it in and started using the laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the “Batteries” [widget](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT211328). You can edit/remove it by long pressing on it.

Likely it got added by mistake by somebody using your iPad.

Comment: it's actually my wife's, but she _never_ (literally) used it, so when mine disappeared, I took it over.  Reading how to install it, I don't see any way that could be done without knowing it.  But that's definitely what it is.

Comment: Yes - I think @JBallin it's an out of the box default widget.

Comment: That iPad was not "out of the box" then or now.  The widget appeared _while_ the iPad was in use months after being put into service.